# Adicionando libs no android com eclipse

Tags: android

normalmente eu pego o jar e coloco dentro da pasta lib do meu projeto, mas ja vi gente que faz a mesma coisa e adiciona pelo "Java Build Path/Add JARs...", tem diferença de só colocar na pasta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você adiciona uma biblioteca pelo Java Build Path/Add JARs, o projeto irá importar para o seu projeto uma **referência**(o caminho aonde está a biblioteca) da biblioteca, por exemplo digamos adiciona uma biblioteca que está na sua área de trabalho(C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop), então o eclipse irá referenciar essa biblioteca caso você posteriormente venha remove ou mover essa biblioteca da sua área de trabalho o ecplise não irá executar o seu projeto, pois falta a biblioteca.

Já você colocando **diretamente** na pasta lib, o projeto irá conter a biblioteca sem uma referencia a outro local diferente que não seja a pasta lib, diferentemente do caso descrito anteriormente.Caso você utilize essa biblioteca em alguma parte do seu código e posteriormente venha deletar ou mover essa biblioteca resultará num erro de compilação.

Comment: agora entendi :)

Comment: de boas, pode ser que eu tenha esquecido de algum detalhe especifico, mas no geral depois de ter utilizado várias plataformas de desenvolvimento, especialmente o java, tenho comigo que esse é o meu entendimento com relação a essa questão bem formulada por você.